# Unable to run pod install command

Tags: cocoapods

When i type in

```
  $ pod install
```

in the terminal i get this error:

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `SFFocusViewLayout (~> 3.0)`
>
> [!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `master` repo. If this is an unexpected
>
> issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose

This is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, "8.0"
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!
target "vid starter" do
pod "SFFocusViewLayout", "~> 3.0"
end

target "vid starterTests" do

end
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

One hint would be to do as the error suggests: `pod repo update --verbose`, and see what information it tells you.

On another note, there seems to be a problem right now with Cocoapods, ruby 2.3 and OS X El Capitan.

If you have installed Cocoapods via gem, you can uninstall it and reinstall it via homebrew. That fixed it for me, apparently because homebrew does not use ruby 2.3...

- `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
- `brew install cocoapods`

I hope this helps.

Comment: please like my question! :)

Comment: The correct command is `brew install cocoapods` not `homebrew install cocoadpods`

However, this probably isn't going to fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the code to say brew instead of homebrew ... :-)